# Slow Update Queries SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite

Is there a particular reason SQLite Updates are so slow when using a select query to get the parameters for the update from another table's data?

For example, If I do:

```
UPDATE cits SET cit_edu_lvl =  cit_edu_lvl + 1, cit_edu_status = 0, cit_age = 18
```

it runs in < 1 second

But if I do

```
UPDATE cits SET cit_edu_lvl = cit_edu_lvl + (
SELECT cit_edu_update_amt FROM education_enrollment ee WHERE ee.cit_ck = 
cits.cit_ck)
WHERE cit_ck in (select cit_ck FROM education_enrollment)
```

To get the same data from other tables and use it to make the update, it takes 12 seconds.

What am I missing? I am running this straight in SQLiteStudio, so batching isn't an issue. If I was to run this in my c# application I would use batching accordingly.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

SQLite does not support a formal update join syntax, which might be the first thing you would try doing here.  But, we can try adding an index to the `education_enrollment` table to speed up the correlated subquery:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON education_enrollment(cit_ck, cit_edu_update_amt);
```

Note that if SQLite does not allow you to add an index to your `education_enrollment` table which already exists, you may have to recreate the table with this index.